# How to get the URL of clicked link?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create an add-on through Mozilla Add-On Builder. What I need to know is how to get the URL of a left clicked link in the active tab through the add-on and open it in a new tab.

I know this process involved adding an eventlistener through a page-mod and then using the tabs module, however I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Edit: (This is what I have so far)

```js
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var tabs = require('tabs');
var pageMod = require("page-mod");

exports.main = function() {


    pageMod.PageMod({
    include: '*',
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScript: "window.addEventListener('click', function(event) { self.port.emit( 'click',event.target.toString() )},false)",
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("click", function(urlClicked) {
            tabs.open(urlClicked);

        });
     }

    }); 

};
```

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? The approach is correct, so without your code I cannot tell you where you made a mistake. Only a suspicion that you tried using the `tabs` module from the content script instead of sending a message back to the extension so that it does that.

Comment: Wladimir,  I haved edited my original post to include the code I have so far.  What I am needing is to be able to get the url of the link clicked and then be able to manipulate parts of that url to form a different one which would then be opened in a new tag.  Make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there is mostly correct and works for me. There are two issues with your content script code however:

- It needs to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser from following the link. Otherwise the linked page will be loaded both in the current tab and the new tab opened by your extension.
- It doesn't check whether `event.target` is actually a link. It could be a child node of the link or it might not be a link at all.

Altogether, your content script should look like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
  var link = event.target;
  while (link && link.localName != "a")
    link = link.parentNode;

  if (link)
  {
    self.port.emit("click", link.href);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

For a non-trivial content script like this, you shouldn't use `contentScript` parameter but rather put it into its own file in the `data/` directory. You can then use `contentScriptFile` parameter when constructing the panel:

```js
contentScriptFile: require("self").data.url("contentScript.js"),
```

Comment: Wladimir, that seems to be working.  I have just one more question.  When I click a link at Google Documents which uses https I get a security error saying "Security Error: Content at https: *** may not load data from https: *** with the stars representing a url.  Do you know what could be causing this?  Also is there a way to determine if a file is being clicked such as a PDF file?

Comment: @Cuyware: I am pretty sure that the security error is not related to your extension - it's an issue with some Google internals. As to recognizing PDF files - this is impossible, at least until the file starts downloading.

Comment: I was thinking the href target would have .pdf in the title, so I was thinking there was a way to test this.

Comment: @Cuyware: File extension is meaningless when dealing with HTTP - the file type is determined by the `Content-Type` header. `http://example.com/foo.pdf` can be a regular HTML page and `http://example.com/getDoc?id=123` can be a PDF file.

Comment: I see.  Well I have solved the issue and your help has been instrumental.  Thanks alot